# WPF: PdfDocument not rendering

Tags: c#, pdf, windows-store-apps

I have a problem with some Windows Store App written in C#.

The app loads a PDF file stored as byte array in database and tries to render the first page in a Image object in its own XAML view. The code is as follows:

```
PdfDocument _pdf = null;
#region Load PDF
using (InMemoryRandomAccessStream ms = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream()) {
    await ms.WriteAsync(getPdfByteArrayFromDB().AsBuffer());
    _pdf = await PdfDocument.LoadFromStreamAsync(ms);
}
#endregion

if (_pdf != null && _pdf.PageCount > 0)
{
    PdfPage _page = _pdf.GetPage(0);
    if (_page != null)
    {
        #region Render page
        using (InMemoryRandomAccessStream ms = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream()) {
            await _page.RenderToStreamAsync(ms);
            BitmapImage bmi = new BitmapImage();
            ms.Seek(0);
            await bmi.SetSourceAsync(ms);
            this.PdfPageImage.Source = bm;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it renders a white image. I tried to do the same by writing a temp file rendering the page as an image and reading it.

```
#region Render page
StorageFile cachedPage = await ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder
        .CreateFileAsync("page.png", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

if (cachedPage != null)
{
    IRandomAccessStream randomStream 
            = await cachedPage.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
    await _page.RenderToStreamAsync(randomStream);

    await randomStream.FlushAsync();
    randomStream.Dispose();
    _page.Dispose();

    BitmapImage bmi = new BitmapImage();
    bmi.SetSource(await cachedPage.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read));
    this.PdfPageImage.Source = bmi;
}
#endregion
```

Exploring the temp folder, there are the temp images with the same size as the original PDF and they are only white images. So i tried to write the stored PDF in a temp file.

```
#region Load PDF
StorageFile cachedPDF = await ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder
        .CreateFileAsync("myPdf.pdf", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
if (cachedPDF != null)
{
    IRandomAccessStream randomStream = await cachedPDF.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
    await randomStream.WriteAsync(getPdfByteArrayFromDB().AsBuffer());

    await randomStream.FlushAsync();
    randomStream.Dispose();

    _pdf = await PdfDocument.LoadFromFileAsync(cachedPDF);
}
#endregion
```

It worked fine with both ways to render the page, so the stored PDF is fine and the trouble comes trying to read the byte array directly from in memory stream. Is there a way to render the PDF page without writing any temp file?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

You have to rewind your `MemoryStream`.

```
using (InMemoryRandomAccessStream ms = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream()) {
    await ms.WriteAsync(getPdfByteArrayFromDB().AsBuffer());
    // The current position is at the end. Rewind to 0.
    ms.Seek(0);
    _pdf = await PdfDocument.LoadFromStreamAsync(ms);
}
```

I should note that by writing it to a temp file, you're creating a new stream which doesn't need to be rewound, which is why it works.

Comment: Of course! Thanks! It was logical, and the funny fact is that I already did that to render the page once the PDF was loaded. But, I'm sorry, white pages strike again. :( +1 anyway.

Comment: I notice that in the bottom one you are calling `ms.WriteAsync` and then `ms.FlushAsync`, but in the top one you are only calling `WriteAsync`. Maybe try flushing?